# file_put_contents saves bad characters to file

Tags: php, file, character-encoding

I have saved some contents (PHPdoc block) to a file using `file_put_contents`, but, when that file get read by another program, it does not read my *phpdoc text*. But when I save (add a space and remove it) the file in Netbeans IDE, the other program can read the phpdoc block without having to fix anything. What could be the cause and how to fix it.

**There is no error in the generated text. I just saved the file using Netbeans and it worked, I did not modify anythinng.**

The code:

```
                $tableOrmAnnotation = "* @ORM\\Table(name=\"song\")";
                $evntHandlerCode = "* @ORM\\EntityListeners({\"hghcgh\\gvhghgBundle\\EventListener\\SongUploadListener\"})";

                $entityCnt = file_get_contents($entityFilePath);

                $entityCnt = \str_replace($tableOrmAnnotation, $tableOrmAnnotation . "\n " . $evntHandlerCode, $entityCnt);

                \file_put_contents($entityFilePath, $entityCnt);
```

The generated text:

```
/**
 * Song
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="song")
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"hghcgh\gvhghgBundle\EventListener\SongUploadListener"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="hghcgh\gvhghgBundle\Repository\SongRepository")
 */
class Song
```

Comment: PHP doesn't really have annotations, it has phpdoc comment blocks which some libraries use in a similar way to how Java uses annotations. However what you have there is a phpdoc block.

Comment: However, Do you have any idea how to fix that problem? There is no error in the phpdoc block. Just bad character encoding.

Comment: What's the evidence that there's bad character encoding? The generated text you shared looks fine to me. Also it's valid ASCII and valid UTF-8 (because ASCII is technically valid UTF-8)

Comment: Well, the evidence, it's because, I do not see other reason that saving the file again in Netbeans (without edit the code) fix the problem.

Comment: Might be the fact that you are using `\n` instead of `PHP_EOL` if this is on windows. Might not be. It's not good to assume what the problem is without gathering more information. For example what are you trying to do and how is it failing?

Comment: I'm on Linux. There is nothing else to say. I just use the code above to replace the texts in a file [that's it]. That file I will use it in a PHP Symfony project (**without moving the file**). But, when I execute the code above, it replaces the texts (*it did his job*). Then, When I execute the PHP Symfony project, Doctrine does not read the phpDoc. But when I save the file back it Netbeans (**add a space then remove it**), then, when I execute the PHP Symfony project, Doctrine does read the phpDoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't any character problem. It was a cache problem. As my project is a Symfony Project and the file I had edited was generated first by Symfony, it cached the annotations(phpdoc) and ignore my following modifications. Then when I launch the project, Symfony read the cache not the entity file. So when I edit the file manually or delete the cache, Symfony regenerates the annotations cache (looks like Symfony reads the file modification date).